# CSS Snap scroll fails on page loads with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll

I'm coding a website (with ajaxify.js and history.js) which includes different `<section>` on vertical scroll with width and height at 100% of the screen (on my homepage and on another page).

To make the navigation a bit nicer, I'm using the new CSS snap scroll function. It works fine on Safari (v.12), Firefox (v.62). But with Chrome (v.69), it really bugs.

Indeed, when my homepage loads on Chrome the snap effect doesn't work. So I go to check on the other page having the effect, it still doesn't work... but if I come back to visit my homepage (without reloading the site because it's in Ajax) the snap effect works!

I'm applying the class "snap" to the `<body>` tag (as the scroll container) and the class "snap-section" to `<section>`.

Here is my css for `<body`:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: mandatory;

  -webkit-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
      scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);

  -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

The CSS for each `<section>`:

```
section.snap-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  scroll-snap-align: start !important;
}
```

This bug drive me nuts... I've tried everything like removing the Ajax but it still makes the same fail. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue.

Found a work around by not applying the "snap-type" property until after the page loads with jquery. Annoying to have to do it this way, but works.

Try the following:

```js
$('body').addClass('scroll-snap');
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.scroll-snap {
  -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: mandatory;

  -webkit-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
      scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);

  -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section.snap-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
/* you can lose the !important */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<section class="snap-section" style="background-color:orange">
</section>
<section class="snap-section" style="background-color:yellow">
</section>
<section class="snap-section" style="background-color:red">
</section>
<section class="snap-section" style="background-color:blue">
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution: if I load the page for the first in Chrome (with nothing in the cache), it doesn't work, but when I refresh the page it works.

Comment: I can't compare apples to apples as I'm on chrome v 70.0.3538.77 - BUT I can tell you that it works with the cache totally cleared. Tested on chrome on PC and mac. Where are you running the script? Make sure it's running after page load.

Comment: I understand, I didn't test it on a PC just on Mac. The website I'm developing is a Wordpress so I run the script in the footer (with a JS file). I've had a settimeout of 2s before applying the class and it seems to work. Thanks!